# Access: Insert data into Two Tables with foreign key relationship

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

For the sake of scale I created an example of my problem to replicate my issue.

Let's say I have 3 tables:

Person

```
| PID      | PName | City  |
 Autonumber  Text    Text
```

Purchase

```
|PurchaseNo | PID  | Item |
 Autonumber  Number  Text
```

Import

```
|Pname| City | Item
 Text   Text   Text
```

So essentially the Person and Purchase table have a 1 to many relationship where each person can make 1 to many purchases. PID is the PK of Person while being the FK of the Purchase table. So if I was doing straight up data entry things would be fine. But the data comes in every morning and I have to import it. It comes in the form of the Import table which is formatted like the one I have shown.

So my issue is how do I distribute a table of imported data to two tables while maintaining the integrity of their 1 to many relationship.

One approach I took was trying to use @@identity, here is the code I used in vba:

```
 Option Compare Database

Public Sub IMPORTRE()

  On Error GoTo errHandler
    Dim wrk As DAO.Workspace
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim lngInvoiceID As Long

    Set wrk = DBEngine.Workspaces(0)
    Set db = wrk.OpenDatabase(CurrentDb.Name)
    With wrk
      .BeginTrans
      db.Execute "INSERT INTO Person SELECT PName,City FROM Import", dbFailOnError
      lngInvoiceID = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT @@IDENTITY")(0)
      db.Execute "INSERT INTO Purchase SELECT " & lngInvoiceID & " As PID, Item FROM Import ", dbFailOnError
      .CommitTrans
      Debug.Print "Inserted Invoice header and detail for Invoice " & lngInvoiceID
    End With

exitRoutine:
    If Not (db Is Nothing) Then
       db.Close
       Set db = Nothing
    End If
    Set wrk = Nothing
    Exit Sub

errHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, vbExclamation, "Error in transaction"
    wrk.Rollback
    Resume exitRoutine

End Sub
```

Which works fine and dandy except for one thing. The PID will always be the last value imported.

So my question is, how do I go about tackling this problem. Is it my code? Or am I over complicating a simple issue? To reiterate, what I'm wanting to do is insert data from my import table into two tables that have a foreign key relationship.

Comment: You need to check if the PName exists before creating it. If it exists, use that key. If not, create it and use the new key. Which begs the question - is pName unique? if it is, why bother with a numberic FK that must be looked up? If not, this isn't overly doable since you don't know the pID.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your names are unique you can do this with 2 queries.  The first inserts people from the import sheet that do not already exists in your `Person` table.

```
INSERT INTO Person ( PName, City )
SELECT PName, City
FROM Import
WHERE not Exists (Select PName, City from Person WHERE PName = Import.PName);
```

For your second query you need to use a join.  This will allow you to get the PID of existing users and the items together in one statement.

```
INSERT INTO Purchase ( PID, Item )
SELECT Person.PID, Import.Item
FROM Import INNER JOIN Person ON Import.PName = Person.PName;
```